How do I set up a draggable clip rectangle that completely clips and hides everything on the canvas not lying within the rectangle?
I would like a draggable rectangle over an entire canvas that will hide everything not within the rectangle. Think "fog-of-war" in a video game where you can't see anything outside the rectangle area
Every approach I have taken doesn't hide everything on the canvas. This little app put a bunch of green rectangles on the canvas and is attempting to make a draggable rectangle that hides the whole canvas apart from what is inside the rectangle. I see and can drag the rectangle but no clipping happens. I can see everything on the canvas.
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsRectItem
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath, QPen, QBrush
from PyQt6.QtCore import QRectF, Qt

class ClipRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, rect):
        super().__init__(rect)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsRectItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsRectItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.GlobalColor.transparent))
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.GlobalColor.red, 2, Qt.PenStyle.DashLine))

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        # Draw the rectangle
        painter.setPen(self.pen())
        painter.setBrush(self.brush())
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())
        
        # Set clipping to only inside the rectangle
        clip_path = QPainterPath()
        clip_path.addRect(self.rect())
        painter.setClipPath(clip_path)

class Example(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create a scene
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # Add some example items to the scene
        for i in range(5):
            rect_item = QGraphicsRectItem(i * 100, i * 50, 80, 40)
            rect_item.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.GlobalColor.green))
            self.scene.addItem(rect_item)

        # Create a draggable rectangle for clipping
        self.clip_rect = ClipRectItem(QRectF(50, 50, 200, 150))
        self.scene.addItem(self.clip_rect)

        # Set up the view
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Clip Outside Rectangle Example')

    def drawForeground(self, painter, rect):
        if self.clip_rect:
            clip_path = QPainterPath()
            clip_path.addRect(self.clip_rect.rect())
            painter.setClipPath(clip_path)
            rectf = QRectF(painter.viewport())
            self.scene.render(painter, target=rectf, source=self.sceneRect())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Example()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Probably quite related: How to clip pixmap image according to scene shape. Simply put: setting the clip only has effect from that moment on; since drawForeground() is called after all items have been drawn, clipping the painter afterward is useless, as it will only clip the new drawn contents. This also makes completely pointless your attempt in calling setClipPath() after painting in the paint() override of ClipRectItem. It's also inappropriate to call the scene.render(), as it would just "paint over" what has already been painted.

@musicamante Thank tou for the explanation. What is the solution here? Can the clipping be done before a scene render? Or shall I bite the bullet and render all the objects in my scene within in the paintevent. I concerned that will be inefficient

No, don't try to manually draw items, it's inefficient (especially since you're doing through Python) and unless you're completely aware of the Graphics View aspects (including transformations), it will most certainly result in unexpected behavior. Please take your time to read the post linked above, study the question and its code, and then the answer and the related solutions. There are many ways to achieve what you want, which one depends on the situation, and you have to be aware of the ramifications about both sides.
